# Ubuntu 16.04 freezes after random duration

Tags: 16.04

Good day all together,

first off I know there is a whole lot of other Posts regarding exactly the same topic, but after I've read through quite a lot of them I found that my issue looks a little bit different. I am new to Linux as I disagree with the privacy details of Microsoft's Windows 10 and therefore probably didn't understand some of the things mentioned in said Posts, so I might as well be wrong, and if that's the case I'm sorry for yet another repost.

I installed the OS completely fresh today and noticed that even when I just sit there staring at the desktop, it freezes after a varying amount of time. It's not completely frozen as I can still move the cursor around, but that only works on that single screen it was positioned on during the moment it froze. Neither can I use hotkeys, nor can I click anything.

Before installing Ubuntu 16.04 I had tried installing Linux Mint as well as the LMDE2, both of them had similar issues as well; after a while they simply froze and also gave me lots of different varieties of screen errors. After those screen errors the OS wasn't even able to boot any more, it just crashed on boot every time (which doesn't happen on Ubuntu though, which is why I believe there could possibly be a way of fixing it here).

Answer (score 0):

You should try to update:

- Your drivers

  - Search "drivers" in the Unity Dash and see if there is something unchecked.
- Your Ubuntu

  - Search "update" in the Unity Dash and update your system.

Consider checking the logs for more information. ([This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles) link can help you)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer in advance. I'll try to get it done in the short window of time that I'm given, the freeze seems to happen faster than it used to at the beginning, it crashed 6 times during my attempt to write that question... I'll answer you again after I know more.

Comment: Ever since the update (which is about 5 minutes past by now) it hasn't crashed once. Feeling really dumb now, and thanks again for your help.

Comment: No problem! This little problems help us to form our knowledge about the system. Glad to help. :-)

Comment: Aaaaand just now it froze again. Can you tell me which logs I should possibly check?